# How do I send UDP packet from a specific interface on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

How do I send UDP packet from a *specific* interface on Linux using C? Should I use bind? Is it possible to send UDP from the interface not having IP address?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can bind a socket to a specific interface by using the [`SO_BINDTODEVICE`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) socket option, however this requires root privileges.

Alternately, you can set the [`IP_PKTINFO`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/ip) option, and use `sendmsg` for sending, setting the `in_pktinfo`'s `ipi_ifindex` to the index of your interface.

Comment: Don't you know: is it a crossplatform way? E.g. would it work this way on Windows®?

Comment: @Hi-Angel: I haven't tried it, but apparently you can use the [`IPPROTO_IP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738586(v=vs.85).aspx) `IP_UNICAST_IF` socket option on Windows. This option takes an interface index, and should also work on current Linux systems (was added in 2012 and is present in Linux v3.4).

Comment: Hmm, interesting… I didn't found a mention about the option in GNU/Linux docs, but found [a short note](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.4) that it was added to help WINE project. I hope the WINE project aware of it :D

Comment: Okay, I found a mails when a wine developer requested the feature, and some patch, possibly from wine developer too. But about was it implemented it the WINE or not, I found only [this patch](https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-patches/2012-October/119376.html). Not sure what it does, but I am suppose that it checks if the linux kernel defined but `IP_UNICAST_IF`  not, so fall back to old implementation. If suppose that WINE developers uses up-to-date kernel, then in all the new WINE versions used the real kernel option.

Comment: Could you please have a look on my question ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192809/udp-restreaming-using-socket-resulting-in-null-packets

Comment: Yes, I implemented `IP_UNICAST_IF` for Wine and it's been supported since Linux 3.3.

Answer (score 10):

Use bind. You cannot send UDP packets via an interface that does not have an IP address, because UDP uses the Internet Protocol and the Internet Protocol requires an IP address.

Comment: Unless you send them as raw packets.

Comment: @nategoose That would be cheating.

Comment: Bind does not help. The source IP of the UDP packet is correct (i.e. it's the IP of the interface I'm trying to send from) but the packet itself goes from the default interface.

Comment: @Jack: You probably have a misconfigured routing table.

Comment: Could you please have a look on my question ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192809/udp-restreaming-using-socket-resulting-in-null-packets

Answer (score 0):

You need to use socket option IP_MULTICAST_IF.

See here: [Multicast-HOWTO-6.html](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Multicast-HOWTO-6.html)

Comment: Wouldn't that only work for multicast? (also, appears to require an address)