# UDP restreaming using socket resulting in NULL packets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, video-streaming

I am implementing a UDP video redirection feature. Ideally incoming video packets should be processed and redirected to a specified output interface (eth0 or eth1). Here's how it's implemented:

1. User selects the interface from a webui. The interface gets passed to the backend
2. Video packets are processed using OpenCaster suite ([here](https://github.com/aventuri/opencaster))..the following libraries are being used in order to process the packets:
   tsfixcc, tsdiscont, tsvbr2cbr,tstimedwrite, tspcrrestamp and tsudpsend.
3. I modified [tsudpsend](https://github.com/nexgenta/opencaster/blob/master/tools/tsudpsend/tsudpsend.c) as follows to support binding the socket to a specific interface and there is no compilation error and I think it's working fine.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *opt;
    opt = argv[5];
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0) {
        perror("socket(): error ");
        return 0;
    }

    struct ifreq ifr;
    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, opt);
    if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr)<0){
        fprintf(stderr,"ioctl(): error ");
    }

    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, opt, strlen(opt))>0){
        fprintf(stderr,"setsock(): error ");
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "The bind is done on interface %s \n", opt);
    fprintf(stderr, "opt length is %zu \n", strlen(opt));
    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, (void *)&ifr, sizeof(ifr)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Server-setsockopt() error for SO_BINDTODEVICE");
        close(sockfd);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem: when I do a packet capture on the selected interface (eth0 or eth1), the processed packets are NULL packets not video data packets as follows

```
1054354 1127.215289 192.168.78.196 -> 239.1.1.1    MPEG TS 1358 NULL packet
1054355 1127.216366 192.168.78.196 -> 239.1.1.1    MPEG TS 1358 NULL packet
1054356 1127.217405 192.168.78.196 -> 239.1.1.1    MPEG TS 1358 NULL packet
1054357 1127.218462 192.168.78.196 -> 239.1.1.1    MPEG TS 1358 NULL packet
1054358 1127.219549 192.168.78.196 -> 239.1.1.1    MPEG TS 1358 NULL packet
```

Any suggestions or ideas on why this is happening ? Any advice please?

Comment: Why are you closing the socket?

Comment: BTW, you should use `perror()` to report errors from system calls, so it will show the error message.

Comment: Your first `setsockopt()` test is wrong, it should be `< 0`, not `> 0`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions...the socket is closed in the original file that I'm modifying ...I'm modifying an existing code base. fprintf is being use to redirect stderr to a log file. The log file content is as follows:
The bind is done on interface eth0
opt length is 4

Comment: Never mind my first question, now I see that `close(sockfd)` is inside the `if`. You should indent your code so it's understandable.

Comment: I can't think of any way this code could affect the contents of the packets being sent.

Comment: You never initialize `opt`. what is `strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, opt)` supposed to copy?

Comment: opt is being initialized by passing the arguments from the front-end..opt is either (eth0 or eth1)

Comment: As far as I know, socket bindtodevice shouldn't affect the packets content. That's why I'm curious to know what could be the problem root cause.

Comment: Are you sure BINDTODEVICE does what you want? The man page says that it restricts the input interface of packets. But you say you're trying to set the output interface. I also don't understand why you're doing it twice. Why are you passing `&ifr`?